# Sleep never continues execution

Tags: php, curl, goutte

I have made a script that checks a server's availability.

The site was down and I was awaiting a fix(I was on call for a client and was awaiting a ticket from the provider), to limit calls I have used [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$available = false;
date_default_timezone_set('doesntMatter');
//The server was more likely to respond after 5 AM, hence the decrese between intervals
$hours = array( //Minutes between calls based on current hour
  0=>30,
  1=>30,
  2=>30,
  3=>30,
  4=>20,
  5=>20,
  6=>10,
  7=>10,
  8=>10
);
$lastResponse = null;
while(!$available) {
    $time = time();
    $hour = date('G', $time);
    echo "\n Current hour ".$hour;
    try {
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'www.someSiteToCheck.com');
        $available = true;  //When the server returns a stus code of 200 available is set to TRUE
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException $e) {}
    if(!$available) {
        $secondsToSleep = $hours[$hour]*60;
        echo "\n Sleeping for ".$secondsToSleep;
        sleep($hours[$hour]*$secondsToSleep); //Sleep until the next request
    } else {
        exec('start ringtone.mp3'); //Blast my stereo to wake me up
    }
}
```

### Problem:

When I started the script it went in a 1800 second sleep and froze, it didn't re-execute anything

### Given:

1. I tested my script with a sleep of 160 (for ex) and it made multiple calls
2. Checked my power settings so that the machine wouldn't go in stand-by
3. Checked error logs
4. (Even if obvious) I ran in CLI
5. Checked [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) documentation for issues but nothing
6. Couldn't find anithing related

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put this is a cronjob?

Comment: Looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206226/sleep-function-on-php), it seems it isn't uncommon to have issues with long sleeps in PHP.

Comment: @jeff: Not really because I would use it 1 per month maximum, and with this I have control over the interval, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an error in your logic.
For example:
When it's 5AM
Then `$secondsToSleep` is `20*60` = `1200sec;`
When you call the sleep function you multiply it again with 20
`sleep($hours[$hour]*$secondsToSleep);` => `sleep(20*1200);` => `24000sec` => `6,66... hours`

Comment: Damn...thank you...I was too sleepy...the smallest bugs break you down...I also added at some point a random int (but removed in the end)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply update your sleep parameter the result should be as expected.

```
if(!$available) {
    $secondsToSleep = $hours[$hour]*60;
    echo "\n Sleeping for ".$secondsToSleep;
    sleep($secondsToSleep); //Sleep until the next request
}
```

Comment: Somebody downvoted for no reason, I hate these people

Comment: I think they were expecting a detailed explanation on how y * y is not the same as y ;)